# Replacing regex pattern with another string works, but replacing with NONE replaces all values

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to replace all strings in a column that start with 'DEL_' with a NULL value.

I have tried this:

```
customer_details = customer_details.withColumn("phone_number", F.regexp_replace("phone_number", "DEL_.*", ""))
```

Which works as expected and the new column now looks like this:

```
+--------------+
|  phone_number|
+--------------+
|00971585059437|
|00971559274811|
|00971559274811|
|              |
|00918472847271|
|              |
+--------------+
```

However, if I change the code to:

```
customer_details = customer_details.withColumn("phone_number", F.regexp_replace("phone_number", "DEL_.*", None))
```

This now replaces all values in the column:

```
+------------+
|phone_number|
+------------+
|        null|
|        null|
|        null|
|        null|
|        null|
|        null|
+------------+
```

Comment: Regex replacement is only possible with string data only. `null` is not a string type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

**scala**

```py
df.withColumn("phone_number", when(col("phone_number").rlike("^DEL_.*"), null)
          .otherwise(col("phone_number"))
      )
```

**python**

```py
df.withColumn("phone_number", when(col("phone_number").rlike("^DEL_.*"), None)
          .otherwise(col("phone_number"))
      )
```

**`Update`**

Query-

> Can you explain why my original solution doesn't work? `customer_details.withColumn("phone_number", F.regexp_replace("phone_number", "DEL_.*", None))`

**Ans-** All the ternary expressions(functions taking 3 arguments) are all `null-safe`. That means if spark finds any of the arguments `null`, it will indeed return null without any actual processing (eg. pattern matching for regexp_replace).
you may wanted to look at [this piece of spark repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression.scala#L696)

```scala
  override def eval(input: InternalRow): Any = {
    val exprs = children
    val value1 = exprs(0).eval(input)
    if (value1 != null) {
      val value2 = exprs(1).eval(input)
      if (value2 != null) {
        val value3 = exprs(2).eval(input)
        if (value3 != null) {
          return nullSafeEval(value1, value2, value3)
        }
      }
    }
    null
  }
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Can you explain why my original solution doesn't work?