# How to replace values by None if string contains character pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, nonetype

I want to **replace** every string in my pandas df column `departments` **with None** if it contains a `)`

```
         departments   var1   var1.1
   1      transport     aa      uu
   2      industry)     bb      tt
   3      aviation)     cc      tt
```

how the dataset **should** look like

```
         departments   var1    var2
   1      transport     aa      uu
   2      None          bb      tt
   3      None          cc      tt
```

A similar solution is here:
[Replacing regex pattern with another string works, but replacing with NONE replaces all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052229/replacing-regex-pattern-with-another-string-works-but-replacing-with-none-repla)

How can i transform it to base python as i dont use spark?

```
df.withColumn("departments", when(col("departments").rlike("\)"), None)
          .otherwise(col("departments"))
      )
```

Comment: so is the above df shown a pandas df or a spark df?

Comment: my df is a pandas df

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. You could use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) function to find out whatever values in `departments` column has `)` then using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with respect to values which we got in m variable setting None to those values.

```
m = df['departments'].str.contains('\)', na=False)
df.loc[m,'departments'] = None
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values. The missing values will need to be explicitly filled with True or False prior to using the array as a mask.

Comment: @id345678, sure, I have edited my answer, kindly take a look to it and let me know how it goes then.